# Corrupted File After File Upload - file size is different

Tags: php, html, apache

I'm running on RHEL 6.2, PHP 4.4.9 and Apache 2.2.15, after the most recent upgrade the file upload logic no longer works. Basically, the file upload seems to be uploaded successfully (no errors returned), but the file is corrupted. The file types can be any file types, and the file size of the uploaded file is always larger than original size. I just compared the source .txt file to the destination .txt, the destination file includes

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="final.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
```

in the .txt file. Basically, it added extra text to the destination file. I am not sure what is going on.

I'm not sure if I need to configure something in php.ini or httpd.conf with this error. Any help would be appreciated. Mary

Below is the code that I tried to test:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
// echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
if (file_exists("/tmp/wangtest/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
{
echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
 }
else
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
"/tmp/wangtest/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
echo "Stored in: " . "/tmp/wangtest/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
}
}
?>
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
 enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label for="file">Filename:</label>
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please format your code Mary. In the editor put 4 spaces before each line to make it indent and look like code here.

Comment: What text got added? Is it related in anyway? Is it possibly header text?

Comment: @Jeffman I reformatted the question to make the added text stand ut.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code (although I'm running 5.5.2 - 4.4.9 is *ancient*). What did you upgrade?

Comment: I upgraded Apache, PHP, and OS (to RHEL 6.2 now).
The only file that I could compare was a .txt file.  I did a quick diff, and saw, the uploaded file had added "Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="final.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain" and then started copying the first line again in the middle section of the file. 
I read a post, and someone mentioned that en_US would help, but everything is in English.  Another post mentioned about special Unicode characters before<?php which I didn't see.  I used Notpad++.  I think it is a header text problem, but not sure what caused it.

Comment: Try `is_uploaded_file()` if it returns true. If it does, then that is Apache issue, otherwise a `php.ini` option - This is the very first thing you need to figure out

Comment: I added is_uploade_file() and it returned true.

Comment: It is indeeded a header text problem.  When my the .txt file exceeded certain length, it added the "----------------------------18756118404966
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="a longer text file.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain" and lots of duplicating text.  I rechecked my php.ini and everything seems to be fine.  Any other ideas?  Not sure what I need to modify httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! I needed to change the httpd.conf.  Has been very frustrating....
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=19263

Mary